# selenium не находит элемент

Tags: python, selenium

Пытаюсь парсить вайлдбериз, на названия товара

```
def func():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('')
    driver.get('https://www.wildberries.ru/catalog/0/search.aspx?sort=popular&search=платье+женское')
    time.sleep(5)

    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="c27949338"]')
```

Выдает даную ошибку

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="c27949338"]"}
```

обращался к разным элементам, но все равно одно и тоже

Comment: а не проще написать ```(By.ID, 'c27949338')```? Так он точно должен обратиться к элементу, тк как id у каждого элемента уникален

Comment: @OtetsValerian Ну оно меня отлично посылает туда, куда и в первый раз. Короче говоря, все равно не работает

Answer (score 1):

Я так понял, что у них при каждом открытии окна выскакивают случайные картинки, поэтому по id искать не вариант. Вот по CSS селекторам можно. Вариант для первой страницы, выбираем почти все платья.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)
select = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.product-card__wrapper")
print(f"Всего найдено    {len(select)}  шт.")
for s in select:
    print(s.text)
time.sleep(5)
driver.quit()

Всего найдено    110  шт.
Промо товар
-47%
3 180 ₽ 6 000 ₽
BASTEMПлатье женское нарядное вечернее коктейльное миди
26
Доставка послезавтра
ДЕНЬ ШОПИНГА
В корзину
Промо товар
-54%
2 755 ₽ 5 990 ₽
LANA FABRICEПлатье женское праздничное футляр
30
Доставка послезавтра
ДЕНЬ ШОПИНГА
В корзину
-75%
2 272 ₽ 9 090 ₽
....................
```